# Generating synthetic RNA-Seq data for performance assessment of new algorithm

Tags: rna-seq, simulated-data, dna

I want to generate synthetic miRNA data for the performance assessment of the newly developed algorithm designed for miRNA data analysis. There are several synthetic sequence simulators available in the published literature, such as wgsim, dwgsim, ART, inSillicoseq, mason,  NEAT, BEER, polyester, RSEM, SimSeq, etc. All of these tools are either for DNA or transcriptome profiles. Can anybody please suggest the following:

1. Can synthetic DNA sequence simulators (ART, wgsim, dwgsim) generate synthetic miRNA data?
2. Some tools, such as CAMPAREE, RSEM, and RNA-Seq simulator, generate RNA-seq data, but I think these tools generate mRNA data, and I am unsure whether I can use them for my miRNA data analysis.

Please suggest. I very much appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks